# Can I send fcm notifications to Firebase UserIds instead of device tokens?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I see examples where you have to extract device tokens and store them in a db to be able to send notifications to that device.

I wondered if I could use Firebase user ids to send a select list of users notifications skipping the need for tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You need to implement a custom notification sender from the `firebase cloud function` to send by user IDs. But you can't ignore the `FCM` tokens. You must register a valid `FCM token` of the user's device to trigger per device notification. Check the following guideline:

[FCM Push Notifications for Flutter](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/)

Answer (score 2):

No firebase is not support to send notification using userID.

You have to integrate FCM package for getting token if firebase using below link :
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

After getting token then only you can use this token and send the notification.

Other way of sending notification is the **topic**.
For topic i am giving you below link :
https://www.filledstacks.com/post/push-notifications-in-flutter-using-firebase/